# MATLAB Parfor with high number of iterations not starting

Tags: matlab, parfor, matlabpool

I am running Matlab 2014a and trying to start a script with parfor. However it gets stuck at

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 16 workers.
```

I run a test script before and it worked ok. The difference is that the test script has 4 iterations of parfor and 2 arrays of 5x12x3x4 size which are filled in the parfor loop, whereas the main script has 100 iterations and 2 arrays of 31x12x3x100 size.
Any ideas how to make it run?
Thanks!

EDIT: here is a simplified version of my code to illustrate the problem, please note that this version, where I don't include the calculations actually works. It is not feasible to include the calculations as they involve other Matlab and a Python script. Also, when I say stuck, I mean that I am not getting any output from the `disp(output)` line.

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

disp('starting');
results_nb = zeros(31,12,3,100);
results_ht = zeros(31,12,3,100);
progress = zeros(1,100);

parfor iter = 1:100

    t = getCurrentTask(); 
    output = ['Worker:' num2str(t.ID) ', Iteration:' num2str(iter)];
    disp(output);
    j_idx=0;
    results_nb_iter=zeros(31,12,3);
    results_ht_iter=zeros(31,12,3);
    for j=[10,20,50]
        j_idx=j_idx+1;
        for i=1:31
            line_nb = zeros(1,12);
            line_ht = zeros(1,12);

            %line_nb = some calculations
            %line_ht = some calculations

            results_nb_iter(i,:,j_idx)=line_nb;
            results_ht_iter(i,:,j_idx)=line_ht;

        end
    end
    results_nb(:,:,:,iter)=results_nb_iter;  
    results_ht(:,:,:,iter)=results_ht_iter;

end

save('results')

exit
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Why do you think its stuck? maybe its just taking very long

Comment: @SardarUsama not sure how to provide one in this case, there is quite a bit happening in my script, involving matlab and python scripts. When I simply assign 0-s to the rows in the loop, it works. I guess I am not looking for exact solution, but rather a tip on what can make my loop run.

Comment: @AnderBiguri this is possible, but taking 1 day to start a loop is the same to me as being stuck.

Comment: @shiftyscales but its not taking 1 day to start the loop. The code you show starts the loop. It says "connected to 16 workers". That means that it has started and connected to it. Wherever it is stuck, its after the starting of the parallel pool

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thanks, fair enough. I have edited the question to make it more clear what I mean.

Comment: @shiftyscales but `disp()` will only display at the end, when the core finishes the task, non-sequentially. You are not measuring what you think you are. You can not add print statements to a parallel loop to know when it is being executed. That dips will, at some point, queue up to the IO stream, and when the process is free (often after the parallel pool ends its math) it will process the IO stream and actually print to screen. This all hints to what I said in the beginning: "this is just taking very long".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deduction is wrong because your measurement is wrong.

`disp()` inside a parfor loop is not ensured to print to screen exactly when the worker gets to it, it is instead queued and when the worker is free, it will send it to the client to print.

To keep progress of a parfor execution, you need [`parallel.pool.DataQueue`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.dataqueue.html)

Read also this other Mathworks post about the same topic: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/372416-how-can-i-display-the-progress-of-a-parfor-or-parfeval-loop-in-matlab-r2017a-and-newer

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I need. However DataQueue was apparently introduced in 2017 and I am running 2014a. Are there alternatives in that version that I can use?

Comment: @shiftyscales huh that is a 6 year old version.... I have no idea if there was something like this then.

Comment: I used parfor_progress for this in the end: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24594-parfor-progress-monitor

Comment: @shiftyscales fantastic. That is written by one of the authors of the parallel toolbox, so its likely that `parallel.poop.DataQueue` is an advanced version of the same thing.